# The mysterious case of the random leakage current

Tags: led, debugging, led-driver, leakage-current

***Disclaimer:*** I already know the solution of this circuit debugging conundrum (and it is not trivial), and I'll post it after some time, so that other people could give their contribution to this mystery story! I think it may have some educational value for circuit designers!

Some years ago (~8, IIRC) I stumbled upon a very interesting special offer at a local general store: some very nice (so I thought) Osram DOT-IT LED light appliances at half the price.

[image]

As you can see, they were small appliances, powered by three
AAA batteries, encasing three very bright white LEDs. The whole
thing was switched on through a soft switch actuated by
pressing the transparent dome. At 1st press the three LEDs
would turn on, and at every subsequent press one of the LEDs
would turn off. So you could have the possibility to choose
the amount of light the appliance would produce. The outer
case, besides the transparent plastic dome, was very strong
anodized aluminium, with the back cover being plastic with a
strong magnet, which allowed to stick the thing to the
fridge, the car body shop or whatever suitable metallic
surface you might want.

Since at the time LED lighting was very expensive here in Italy, and small gadgets like those were either monstrously expensive or totally crappy, I thought it a very good idea to buy a dozen of them (I first tried with just one unit, and I verified it made very strong light and was of very high quality). I intended to use them as emergency lights in every room of my house and in my car.

All was fine until a brief black out happened after about 6 months. To my great disappointment, about 10 out of 12 of the things had their batteries dead!

Of course my first thought was "crappy leaky soft switch" and I ran for my micro-ammeter! Effectively I found a couple of units that had excessively high leakage currents (~1 mA), but the other ones had a quite honest ~20 μA. I was puzzled.

I replaced all the batteries in the low-leakage ones and decided to give them another try.

After a couple of months, surprise, they failed again! I measured the leakage again and got different results. Some units sported the terrible ~1 mA leakage, whereas the other were "normal". Moreover, I retested the two units which originally showed high leakage and... they didn't leak any longer!!!

I was fed off and since I had got no more time to waste on the issue back then, I scrapped them all, put them in a junk box (after all, they had three nice and expensive white LEDs in them, and I planned to salvage them) and forgot about them.

I found them again a couple of weeks ago and, in a reorganization frenzy, I thought to dismantle the units and salvage the LEDs. So I discovered that the internal circuitry was a tiny PCB holding just a momentary switch, the LEDs, a driver chip and a cap. The PCB is shown in the photos below (for curiosity I tried finding a datasheet for that driver chip, but with no luck).

[image]
[image]
[image]

I tested the PCBs again, just for fun, and I still got the erratic leakage behavior I had observed before, but in the process I finally discovered the culprit.

**Guess what was the cause of that random and erratic leakage!**

Comment: A bad capacitor?

Comment: @winny Nope, unfortunately!

Comment: Dirt between plus and minus pads?

Comment: Was it related to repeated board flex/stress?

Comment: Oh! Is the solder joint for the push button bad?

Comment: @winny No dirt issue!

Comment: @Cheibriados no mechanical stress!

Comment: @winny no solder joint issues either!

Comment: Whiskers (caused by incomplete etching) on the PCB, bridging traces?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Interesting theory! But not the real culprit!

Comment: Even if it didn't cause it, one of the button solder joints looks broken.

Comment: RF pickup? Can we see the cause in any of the pictures?

Comment: @Winny Oh, that is not significant. That PCB is the only one I've got left, and it is not in the best conditions. When I perform the dismantling I didn't even think I would post a question here, so I didn't keep them.

Comment: @Neil_UK. The cause is not really in the photos. As for RF pickup..., it is not the culprit. But you are coming a little closer...!

Comment: The protruding pins made contact with the back cover?

Comment: @Mario. Nope. No accidental contacts of any sort.

Comment: EMI problems? Sensitivity to ESD?

Comment: @mario No ESD problems. EMI? In a sense ... you are getting closer! :-)

Comment: +1 for a interesting question, but also because of pictures that were relevant, properly focused, and with the right crop to show what is needed but leave out what is not needed.  This would be a good question to refer to for how to properly post pictures of circuits.

Comment: Incident light on the LEDs?

Comment: Bad battery holders?

Comment: Mechanical stress of the PCB/assembly  by the magnet?

Comment: Looks like it is a clone of a popular 8bit uController.  I must say it was not easy to find a datasheet. But here is a link to a OTP version of an EMP78P153S in Chinese (I think). You will need to cut and paste the link carefully, it has forward and back slashes "\", "/"  -  http://www.datasheet.hk/download.php?file=0406\hs108_4612284.pdf

Comment: @KalleMP Wow! Nice find! Thanks! Now I wish I could read Chinese! :-P :-) I didn't suspect it could have been an MCU, though. These little beasts are everywhere! :-) I fear we'll see some tiny MCU priced at the same level of a single PN2222 BJT one of these days!

Comment: Just to support what @JohnD said.  I vote for light being more likely to affect the circuit than magnetic fields.  If you ever want to you could try cover the LEDs with thick dark black cardboard or aluminium foil tape and see if you can achieve latch up.  Then remove the magnets and wave them in and out of bright light and see if they might latch up.  Also see if there are any unconnected pins that might pick up static charge though the aluminium case should protect from much of that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suspect something to do with the strong magnet (I wouldn't have suspected it, except that it must be an interesting answer or you wouldn't have posed the question).  Perhaps having the magnetic field induces a current in a loop somewhere.  Was the leakage higher when there was more area between the wires connecting to the battery?  Or it could be a current in some other loop.

Comment: Wow! We have a winner here! :-)

Comment: As I understand it, it's a permanent magnet mounted on the unit in the same position relative to the electronics.  This therefore couldn't induce any voltage or current since the magnetic field doesn't change at the electronics.  Even if the magnet is moved as part of replacing the batteries, it would presumably be in a fixed location during the initial test after replacing the batteries and re-assembling the unit.

Comment: I'll post an answer for the details, but you surely deserve the acceptance mark (also for your detective skills!).

Comment: @Lorenzo: I was typing my comment while you were typing yours.  Please explain how you think the magnet upset the electronics, and why the points I made don't apply.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Nice analysis, and you are right in some respect. And this is why it took me a great deal of effort to understand the thing!

Comment: The problem is twofold: i noticed the "latch-up" and consequent increase in the leakage when I moved the magnet (disassembled) near the PCB under test. Not always the movement caused mischief, and this probably has to do with how the magnetic flux interacted with the PCB and the driver....

Comment: Some weird Hall effect internal to the chip? Normally this would only be a problem if a current was actually flowing. Perhaps on first assembly everything would be fine as no current was flowing but when the button was pressed current flows and a Hall voltage causes a latch-up inside.

Comment: One possible cause was that during battery replacement, sometimes, the fault occurred....but this wouldn't explain why this occurred in units that didn't leak after battery replacement...

Comment: @OlinLathrop - You're right; I forgot that it's only a *changing* magnetic field that would be important.  Your answer is probably closer to the root cause, where the magnet is just the catalyst.

Comment: But then I noticed that sometimes the problem arose when an operating unit with the magnet attached were moved near ferromagnetic items. For example when I attached an appliance to the fridge!

Comment: Probably the interaction with large masses of magnetic materials disturbed the static magnetic field in which the PCB was immersed in such a way to provoke a sufficient variation in the magnetic flux so as to induce a current in the PCB or inside the chip.

Comment: @Lorenzo:  Moving magnetic things near a permanent magnet does change the magnetic field.  The derivative of the field should still be quite small, particularly on the other side of the magnet, but it would be non-zero.  A least it's not impossible for this to be a cause, but the effect should be very weak.  The Hall effect is more likely, since it works on the instantaneous magnitude of the field.  Perhaps as Transistor said, this caused strange voltages in the chip when current flowed, which could possibly cause some strange latching.

Comment: Since the magnet was not built-in in the back cover, but was optional, i.e. it came with an adhesive side with which you could attach it to the back cover, I suspect that the designers didn't perform tests on the unit while the magnet was in place.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I cannot really say whether Hall effect or small disturbance in magnetic flux is the real mechanism at play. I only invertigated the external behavior. The Hall theory is also interesting!

Comment: Could it be mechanical - the magnet is actually pulling the switch contacts into very weak contact?

Answer (score 15):

***Here is the summary of my investigations and my findings on the mysterious case of the random leakage current.***

---

When I began dismantling the units, I also got curious and wanted to research a rational cause for that odd behavior. I had no luck until I almost inadvertently moved the magnet near a powered-up PCB. The ammeter jumped to about 2mA and stabilized at a slightly lower value.

At first I thought it was just a mechanical effect due to my handling of the PCB, but after repeated tests I verified that there was a clear correlation between moving the magnet near the PCB and having that sort of "latch-up".

It wasn't sure-fire, though, because it depended in an unclear way on the magnet orientation and the direction of the movement and also on the speed with which I moved the magnet.

I couldn't assess the real mechanism, but the cause was clear. The interaction of the PCB (and most probably the driver chip) with the moving magnet.

I also verified that the latch-up could happen when moving an assembled unit near a massive ferromagnetic body, such as when attaching the unit to a fridge. But the phenomenon in this case was less repeatable and more erratic.

The options that came to my mind were obviously two:

- induced current generated by the variation of magnetic flux linked with some loop
- Hall effect disturbing the normal behavior of some semiconductor components inside the driver chip

I cannot say for sure which is the real culprit between those two. I leave the final decision to the experts on EE.SE who are more knowledgeable than I am on such topics.

I cannot be sure, but I suspect that whoever was in charge to test the prototype didn't perform proper testing when the magnet was in place. In fact the magnet wasn't built-in in the back cover of the units, but was provided as an add-on in the package. You had the option to stick it to the back cover since one side of the magnet was adhesive.

---

*I hope you enjoyed this little mind-teaser, vaguely inspired to Sir Arthur Conan-Doyle's novels.*

Comment: "When recording data,
if you see something that looks funny, 
record the amount of 'funny' ".

Tom Milligan as quoted by Bob Pease

Answer (score 7):

This kind of symptom smells of missing pulldown (or pullup, depending on topology) resistor on a FET gate.  All is fine if the system powers up without the startup transient activating the FET.  If that is successful, all is well.  If not, the system latches into some wierd state that manages to draw some current.

I notice this is a single-sided board.  That means thru-hole leads are only held by the solder meniscus on one side of the board, not inside the plated hole and on both sides like on a two layer board.  After enough mechanical stress or thermal cycling, such solder joints can get flaky.  This can be very hard to see, even with a jewler's loupe.  I've personally seen such a board fail in seemingly random ways, and visual inspection didn't reveal the problem, even though I was looking for bad solder joints.  Reflowing every joint and adding additional solder fixed the problem.

Another cause for such symptoms is that the button is pressed all the time.  However, I'm figuring this isn't the case because then the lights wouldn't have worked in the first place.  That kind of pushbutton has a positive click feel.  The only way this problem could happen in your circumstance is if the button worked right for the first three clicks, then got stuck on with the click that turned the light off.  It is unlikely that so many units would work fine for three clicks, then all get stuck on the forth, so I'm not thinking this is the problem.

I can think of scenarios where a badly designed circuit can latch into a unintended state with the power supply glitching and bouncing as the batteries are installed, possibly depending on whether the button was pressed or not at the time.  However, all these scenarios would leave the unit obviously inoperative immediately.  I'm assuming that you tested each unit thru at least one cycle of ON-OFF before declaring it ready and sticking it on a wall or whatever.

Comment: Interesting theory! I cannot comment on the quality of the PCB build, so it may have eventually developed some problems because of what you point out, but it wasn't the culprit!

Comment: BTW, I only discovered the cause, not the actual mechanism. Effectively, some kind of latch-up might have been involved in the mechanism, but the cause was not mechanical stress or bad solder joints.